# Magento 2: How to avoid objectManager in Model?

Tags: magento2, overrides, custom, model, object-manager

I have achieved

[Magento 2: How to change Weight field for DHL Shipping Method [SOLVED]](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149550/magento-2-how-to-change-weight-field-for-dhl-shipping-method-solved)

I tried to put

```
protected $_product;

public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product) {
    $this->_product = $product;
}

public function _getAllItems() {

    $allItems = $this->_request->getAllItems();
    $fullItems = [];

    foreach ($allItems as $item) {
        $this->_product->load($item->getProduct()->getId());
        $itemWeight =  $_product->getData('weight_with_package');
    }
}
```

It's not working :(

Comment: Where is define $item->getProduct()?

Comment: Please check updated question @Rakesh

Answer (score 0):

You can use product API to get product data :

```
protected $_productRepository;

public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository) {
     $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
}

public function _getAllItems() {
     $allItems = $this->_request->getAllItems();
     $fullItems = [];

    foreach ($allItems as $item) {
         $this->_product = $this->productRepository->getById($item->getProduct()->getId());        
        $itemWeight =  $_product->getData('weight_with_package');
    }  
}
```

Hope It works for you, If you will get any issue please contact.

Comment: It's giving `window.checkoutConfig = <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getValue() on null in /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-shipping/Model/Carrier/AbstractCarrier.php:132`

Comment: It's js error , not because of my code