# Magento 2: Carrier with such method not found

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping

When I'm on Checkout Page. Sometimes I'm facing the below error.

> Carrier with such method not found: null, null

I have selected by Shipping Address, Not selected any Shipping Method & Clicked on "Next"

I'm using DHL Shipping Method. I have to override the DHL Shipping Method Model as per my requirement.

[Magento 2: How to change Weight field for DHL Shipping Method [SOLVED]](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149550/magento-2-how-to-change-weight-field-for-dhl-shipping-method-solved)

Not sure if anyone comes across this issue.

Comment: I'm having this issue as well.. Haven't found a fix for it yet. Clicking "Next" again for the second time works. It's just the first time..

Comment: Have you found any solution @Erfan

Comment: Yeah, @Jalpesh, for me it was because of a `collectTotals` call in a custom plugin (after quote load). We made sure it only collects totals when it needs, and it fixed a lot of issues for us.

Answer (score 0):

The above error is triggered when the specified shipping method is not available or is invalid.

As we can see at [vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/ShippingInformationManagement.php:209](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.0/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/ShippingInformationManagement.php#L209) if `getShippingRateByCode` returns false, it throws this exception.

Inside this method, we can see that it's not very complex to understand...

```
    public function getShippingRateByCode($code)
    {
        foreach ($this->getShippingRatesCollection() as $rate) {
            if ($rate->getCode() == $code) {
                return $rate;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

I can think of 3 possible **reasons** for that:

1. You have a saved quote using a shipping method that was disabled
2. When you changed the shipping method, you forgot to add the constant [CODE](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.0/app/code/Magento/Dhl/Model/Carrier.php#L64) or changed its value
3. You've changed the config.xml of the module and forgot to add [<model>](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.0/app/code/Magento/Dhl/etc/config.xml#L19) within the default node. I did that once for the payment method and got a similar error.

I hope any of these suggestions help.

Answer (score 0):

This solution might work for this issue (override `collectRates()` method and set the correct shipping method to quote shipping address) - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64826863/8497354

FYI - Possible M2 core issues:

- https://github.com/webshopapps/module-matrixrate/issues/36
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3789
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25147

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Please refers to doc:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13594

As per doc, with step by step debug, I was able to trace the problem from:

```
// magento/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/ShippingAssignment/ShippingProcessor.php:72
$this->shippingMethodManagement->apply($quote->getId(), $carrierCode, $methodCode);
```

to:

```
// magento/vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Validator.php:374
foreach ($this->_getRules($address) as $rule) {
```

I updated `is_active` field to `0` to rules retrieved by request (that I got by using `$this->_getRules($address)->getSelectSql(true)`) in `salesrule` table.

I was then able to reach payment step.